# How can an answer starting with "I think" and containing just a line be an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am referring to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18657/199):

> I think there is view alter that you can use.

How can this is be an answer? I am not objecting that is correct, or not; I am objecting that doesn't answer to what asked because:

- It starts with "I think". Is the OP unsure of what he is saying, or is he using "I think" just as filler?
- It says, "there is view alter," but it's not clear if he is referring to `view_alter()`, `hook_view_alter()`, or something else. Probably it is referring to `hook_view_alter()`, but you cannot be sure future readers understand what "there is view alter you can use" means.
- There isn't a link to a documentation page, nor a code snippet that would at least help to understand what the OP is talking of.
- The answer could help who knows almost everything about the Views module, but you cannot take the assumption the asker knows every detail about the module for which the question is. If it were so, then probably the asker would not have asked the question.

That "answer" is rather a comment. It is similar to write the following sentence as answer:

> I think you are wrong.

If I am taking the time to say the asker is wrong, I should also taking the time to explain exactly why he is wrong, and what should do instead.

Would those answers be helpful? What would future readers understand reading "I think you are wrong" as answer to a question? Would they immediately get what they should do, by reading that answer?
In the same way, what would future readers understand from, "I think there is view alter that you can use"?

Do we really want more answers like those?

Answer (score 1):

I say we definitely do not want such answers, and the community's opinion is quite clear. It has two comments (one by yourself) making this remark, and it's downvoted thrice, once by me.

Comment: Did you also flag it as not an answer?

Comment: I did not, hadn't previously noticed the answer flags. Done now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If an answer to a question can be considered either correct or incorrect, then it is an answer and shouldn't be flagged for attention.

This doesn't mean that it is a *good* answer, though.  There is a mechanism in place for this [down-voting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down).

That particular answer is gone, but I think it would fall under "no-effort-expended post".

A better way to encourage the community would be to leave a comment on the answer and ask for clarification / expansion.

Comment: Answers should not be flagged for correctness, but that is not the reason I flagged that answer; I flagged it because it doesn't say much to be an answer, first because it seems the OP is not sure of what he is saying, and secondly because it doesn't use the correct term, nor does it contain any link to the documentation. It seems like the OP could not be bothered of writing a more complete answer, and left those few words, which (IMO) have the same effect of writing "I think you are wrong" as answer for another question, without leaving more details.

Comment: Your reasons totally fall under "no-effort-expended post" and potentially "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" criteria for down-voting.  No need to waste the moderators time.

Comment: To notice that the [FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) says, "answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed"; the list that follows that sentence is not exclusive, meaning that answers not matching the listed points are not deleted. As there aren't 20k users, the moderators are the only ones who can delete those kind of "answers" (in fact, the answer I was referring in my answer has not been deleted from the OP); with 3 20k users, and a down-voted answer, it would be easy to delete the answer, if three 20k users vote to delete it.

Comment: On _Drupal Answers_ there aren't enough 20k users to delete answers, which means that most of the work done for deleting answers is done from moderators. On other sites, with more 15k/20k users, deleting posts is not a privilege of moderators (which, for the privileges, are considered 20k users with more privileges).